# Back up the download folder on win10 in OneDrive

Tags: backup, onedrive, windows-backup, file-download

Seems that one drive could only backup "desktop" "documents" "photos",   but not the "download" folder?
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you see the Download folder in the regular window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Downloads folder is sort-off designed for ephemeral data.

However, you can try to do the same thing OneDrive does with the other folders: *Move* it. To do so, open the properties window and go to the “Location” tab:

[image: Downloads folder properties]

Use the “Move” button (or simple enter the path manually). It could be something like `C:\Users\Daniel\OneDrive\Downloads` in my case. Then click OK. If the folder does not exist yet, you’ll have to confirm that it should be created.

You will then be asked whether the existing files should be moved. It is very important you confirm this, otherwise you’ll end up with two “Downloads” folders in your user profile.

Afterwards, your Downloads folder will be redirected inside OneDrive, just like the “Desktop”, “Documents” and “Pictures” folders.

Comment: thanks for answer,  this is not a symbolic link right?  All the files will be move to there?

Comment: Dunno how exactly it works under the hood, but yes, the files will “physically” reside in the OneDrive folder.

Comment: I found the button, thx for your reply also